# How to display different taxonomy post in differnt page by single page template

Tags: php, wordpress

I have Menu's Like Books , Studies , Topic Etc . Now i created a custom post type as Studies and custom taxonomy as Study , Under that i have different category like Books,Topics, Now i need to create a single page template where I need to display Books category Post in Books Menu and Topic Category Post in Topics Menu

Comment: Pass taxonomy dynamically in the page and get post according ....

Comment: @Anand - oh thats fine , okay thankyou :)